# comando linux: git pull origin master fatal error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Tags: linux, git, github, repositorio

Queria sacarme una duda. Estoy vinculando un archivo que hice en github, segui los siguientes pasos:

- Crear repositorio, con un archivo README.md.
- Luego abri terminal de linux e hice lo siguiente:

```sh
git init 
git remote add origin https://github.com/MarceloDiazz/primer-rep.git
git pull origin master
```

Obteniendo:

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
```

DATO: si pongo `git pull origin` funciona pero no se si esta bien ejecutado.

Answer (score 2):

El comando `git pull origin master` intenta actualizar desde la rama `master` de tu GitHub, pero tu repositorio en GitHub no tiene una rama `master`, sino una `main`.

Para ver las ramas de tus remotes:

```sh
git branch -r
```

Sobre `git pull origin`: Lo que hace es actualizar todas las ramas que tengas sincronizadas con ese remote (origin). Si hacés `git pull -v origin` y tenés más de una rama sincronizada entre GitHub y tu copia local (*en el ejemplo las ramas son `main` y `testing`*), entonces vas a ver algo como:

```
 = [actualizado]     testing    -> origin/testing
 = [actualizado]     main       -> origin/main
```

Más información: `man git-pull` y `man git-branch`.

Saludos.